# Custom User Field in Wordpress (Hidden from User)

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to find a way to add a custom field for users in Wordpress, but I don't want this field to be seen by the users. It'll be entered and viewed by an admin, but it shouldn't be shown on the registration page or their profile page.

Is there an easy way to do this? If so, may I be pointed in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [add_user_meta()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_user_meta) function to add any metadata you would like.

In order to display it only to admins level, you should use one of wordpress´s [conditional tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags), in addition to a simple user level check.