# adding rank to profile

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

For all of the trekkies out there.
(moment of silence for spock)

I have been diligently building a star trek fan club website for six months now.  I have avoided using wordpress/buddypress, specifically because we need ranks (ie. crewmen, petty officer, Ensign, Captain, Admiral) for each individual, which can be updated by the owners of the site.  Owners without knowledge of code.

So what I need to do, is add to buddypress rank by text and image to show what the individual's rank is as per star trek standards.

I'm learning still here, so any idea on how to add fields to profiles that allow the updates would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Useful links: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=wordpress+custom+user+field

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom User Field in Wordpress (Hidden from User)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16231162/custom-user-field-in-wordpress-hidden-from-user)

Comment: Hey guys, Thanks so much....I'm  not looking to have hidden fields.  I'm trying to have a field in place that can be seen, but only adjusted by the owners.

Comment: Ignore the part of the linked question that references hiding data from user, it is still what you want - user meta fields. You can make a check when setting it as to the permissions of the user (to ensure they are the site owners) and then show it in various places to all users.